# Reacting to a component being scrolled off screen in a react-native ScrollView

Tags: react-native

Currently I am using a `<ScrollView />` component to handle the scrolling for my items, as I will only ever have a maximum of three items I feel this is appropriate instead of introducing a `<FlatList />`. This component receives a prop called `collapsed` and `onCollapseToggle` which is used to modify the collapse prop that is passed to the child. I have also experimented with the child having it's `collapsed` variable in state, but it seems that modifying the child's state from the parent would be near-impossible.

When scrolling through the `<ScrollView />` when a component is passed up (The user scrolls down far enough that the component is no longer displayed on the screen) I want to execute a function that could potentially change the `collapsed` value that's passed to the item being rendered. This way if a user as expanded an item to view more information about it, and then continues scrolling down the `<ScrollView />` the item would be self-collapsing, without the user having the manually close it through some form of input.

I'm not currently sure about any way to go about this, and any help would be greatly appreciated. I will provide an example of the structure that I am working with, which may help someone come up with a solution. I do not mind restructuring my components.

```
class ContentInformation extends React.Component {
  state = { content: [ ... ] };  

  onCollapseToggle = (index, displayed=true) => {
    const { content } = this.state;
    const arr = content.slice();
    const item = arr[index];
    if(!item) return;

    if(!displayed) {
      if(!item.collapsed) {
        item.collapsed = true;
      }
    } else {
      item.collapsed = !item.collapsed;
    }
    arr[index] = item;
    this.setState({ content: arr });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        { this.state.content.map((content, index) => (
          <Item 
            key={content._id}
            index={index} 
            onCollapseToggle={this.onCollapseToggle}
            {...content} />    
        ); }
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

So basically, as you can see, I only need to figure out when the `<Item />` goes off-screen so I can call `onCollapseToggle(index, false)` to automatically re-collapse the component if it's open.

Comment: It's a bit hard getting what the problem is for you. Are you trying to make items collapse when they go off screen? Either way please add a similar sentence that explains the problem in less words just so we are clear

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how you can detect when an item is offscreen when scrolling.

```
state = { toggleDistance: 0 }    

_handleScroll({nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y}}}) {
    const {toggleDistance} = this.state;
    if (y >= toggleDistance) {
        // The item is offscreen
    }
}

render() {
    <ScrollView
      onScroll={this._handleScroll.bind(this)}>
      <Item 
        onLayout={({nativeEvent: {layout: {y, height}}}) => this.setState({toggleDistance: (y + height)})}/>
      ...
    </ScrollView>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you need a FlatList or a ListView and ScrollView simply doesn't support this use case.

The hint is in the [ScrollView](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.45/docs/scrollview.html) description:

`FlatList is also handy if you want ... any number of other features it supports out of the box.`

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem improving the answer from ivillamil with some adjusts:

```
const [toggleDistance, setToggleDistance] = useState(0);
const [showBottom, setShowBottom] = useState(false);

const onScrollMoveFooter = (event: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeScrollEvent>) => {
const currentOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
if (event.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.height - currentOffset < 
  toggleDistance) {
  setShowBottom(true);
 }  else {
   setShowBottom(false);
  }
};
```

And in the another component:

```
<Component
        onLayout={({
          nativeEvent: {
            layout: { y, height },
          },
        }) => setToggleDistance(y + height)}
      />
```

and so I can conditionally hide what I wanted:

```
{showBottom && (<AnotherComponent/>)}
```